# SymPy polynomial characterization as a dictionary

Tags: python, sympy, polynomials

I have to characterize a very large polynomial expression of many variables (x1,x2,....,xn) as follow:

- the power of each of the monomial terms forms an ordered tuple which will be saved as the keys of a dictionary.
- the coefficient of that monomic expression is saved as the value of that particular key.

Example: if `p=Poly(3*x1**2 -  x1*x2 + 5*x2 +7)`

```
dic={"(2,0)":3 , "(1,1)":-1 , "(0,1)": 5 , "(0,0)": 7}
```

It is very important that the first component of the tuple always be the power associated with x1 and if I run the same code again with a new poly with no x1 variable, it put a zero in its first component.

Answer (score 0):

The Poly method `as_dict` does that, if you specify the variables and their order as the second argument of Poly, for example `Poly(..., (x1, x2))`. Assuming the symbols x1, x2 were already created, this works as follows.

```
>>> p = Poly(3*x1**2 - x1*x2 + 5*x2 + 7, (x1, x2))
>>> p.as_dict()
{(0, 0): 7, (0, 1): 5, (1, 1): -1, (2, 0): 3}
>>> p = Poly(x2 + 5*x2 + 7, (x1, x2))
>>> p.as_dict()
{(0, 0): 7, (0, 1): 6}
```